# Fixed Header for ASP NET Gridview JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I've been searching a lot for ways to make my gridview header fixed I came across this JQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
               // Code to copy the gridview header with style
               var gridHeader = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').clone(true);
                 //Code to remove all the rows but the first row which is header row
                 $(gridHeader).find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                 $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr th').each(function (i) {
                // Here Set Width of each th from gridview to new table th 
                $("th:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")", gridHeader).css('width', ($(this).width()).toString() + "px");
            });
                 // Append Header to the div controlHead
                 $("#controlHead").append(gridHeader); // <-- HERE is WHEN IT DAMAGES OTHER JS FUNCTIONALITY 
                 // Set its position to be fixed
                $('#controlHead').css('position', 'fixed');
                 // Put it on top
                $('#controlHead').css('top', $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').offset().top);
```

It actually works but it makes my other JS functions to malfunction when I append this cloned header to the empty div "gridHeader"
Like this JS Function that is in charge of highlighting the selected row, it just doesn't find the Gridview anymore

```
  // Method that will highlight row
    function gridviewManipulation() {
        // Get Gridview 
        var gridView = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");

        // Loop through the Gridview
        for (var i = 1; i < gridView.rows.length; i++) {
            // Get the radio button of each row in the gridview and see if its checked
            if (gridView.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked == true)
            {
                // Place the color for selection
                gridView.rows[i].style.background = '#9bc27e';

            }
            else if (gridView.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].checked == false && i % 2 == 0)
            {
                // If its even then place white color back
                gridView.rows[i].style.background = '#FFFFFF';
            }
            else 
            {
                // If its odd place the bluish back on
                gridView.rows[i].style.background = '#E3EAEB'; 
            }
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you!!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code that malfunctions. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are using the ID of the element to identify it.

When you run this line:

`var gridHeader = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').clone(true);`

You create a 2nd table element with the same ID. Subsequent calls to that ID are not working as you expect.

I'd try the following to change the id of the cloned table you create:

`var gridHeader = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').clone(true).attr('id', 'newID');`

Comment: Do I change the id for the last line?     
$('#controlHead').css('top', $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').offset().top);

Comment: @Electric I can't really see all of your mark-up, but I believe that wouldn't be necessary.